# problem related to date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

hi
  I have 2 input dates in different format,so please tell me how to iterate through them 
  and convert them into new format using if-else.
  Here is my input:
  String first="Mar 12";
  String second="Feb 23 2010";
  I am trying to convert these different format into new format.

### I have used follwing code:

```
Date date=new Date();
//I used this format for Mar 12
DateFormat dateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd"); 
// Mar 12 gets converted in follwing new format
DateFormat dateFormat2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
//I used this format for Feb 23 2010
DateFormat dateFormat3=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy"); 
// Feb 23 2010 gets converted in follwing new format
DateFormat dateFormat4=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");

date=dateFormat1.parse("first");
first=dateFormat2.format(date);
date=dateFormat3.parse("second");
second=dateFormat4.format(date);
```

---

now I am facing problem,I am not getting how to parse & convert them in new format using  if-else block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat.parse` returns null in case of an error. So, you could do something like this:

```
date = dateFormat1.parse(first, new ParsePosition(0));
if (date == null) {
  date = dateFormat2.parse(first, new ParsePosition(0));
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the last sentence. Was it this that confused too? If yes, I've tested that if no year information is given, then the parsed date will be placed in year 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use *string length* / *no of space in the string*  to differentiate the formats.[as you have only two format.]